# Table Join on distance measures returns NULL

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

I followed every step of this tutorial but when I join the distToRoads and distance in m I get a table distToRoads which contains just the null vaues, why is that?

Tutorial:  https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html [image]

Answer (score 2):

This will only work if the two columns are **exactly** the same. They are likely to be floating point (or real) numbers and so won't be an exact match.

More usually you would join on a common id or name.

Comment: Ok, but what should I do then to get this field "Distance in m" from my csv file to be in my layer in the attribute table?

Comment: you need to join using a common id field - do you have one?

Comment: Hi, I don't have it. Can I perform some other operation besides join to do what I desire?

Comment: You could create a new field in each layer with rounded values, and use the rounded values for the join.